# mysql Join produces an error

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

i have this code, and i cant find the error.

```
public  function show(){

$x=NULL;
$owner = $_SESSION['UID'];
$sql = "SELECT 
kunde.name AS n1, 
rechnung.RechNR AS rnr 
FROM  `rechnung`AS  rr
INNER JOIN  `kunde`
ON rr.KID = kunde.KID
WHERE owner = ? ";
$stmt = $this->mysqli->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bind_param("i", $owner);
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->get_result();
while ($obj = $result->fetch_object()) {
 $x[] = $obj;
}

return $x;
```

}

without the Join I get an Result with the JOIN I got these Message but I don t Know why: Call to a member function bind_param() on a non-object

Thx for Reading.

Comment: You get that message because `prepare` fails, returning `FALSE`. There's no `FALSE->bind_param`. It fails because the SQL is not valid. I'm guessing you need a space between ``rechnung`` and `AS`.

Comment: Any chance the `owner` field is in both tables?  Perhaps it just needs to be given an alias?

Comment: Is your request valid if you try to execute it in a PHPmyAdmin? You should check that $_SESSION['UID'] is valid

Answer (score 3):

You've got to rewrite your SQL statement and use the alias name for the field `RechNr` too.
Instead of `rechnung.RechNR` you've got to use `rr.RechNr` instead:

```
$sql = "SELECT 
kunde.name AS n1, 
rr.RechNR AS rnr 
FROM  `rechnung` AS  rr
INNER JOIN  `kunde`
ON rr.KID = kunde.KID
WHERE owner = ? ";
```

Because you didn't use the alias name, the preparing of the statement did fail.

Comment: +1. Good catch.... (OP didn't just add JOIN, OP also added alias to `rechnung` table.)

Comment: Less to write in the join condition :-) I had the advantage that most identifiers are in German, my first language.